# '$' is undefined in SharePoint Search Display Template

Tags: templates, search, sharepoint, display

I customized a display template. The html display template code is exactly the same as UAT. When I deployed to Prod, I got this error when ran a search:

Display Error: The display template had an error. You can correct it by fixing the template or by changing the display template used in either the Web Part properties or Result Types.

'$' is undefined (CoreRender: ~sitecollection/*catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Search/Item****.js)

I checked in both the html page and js file, there is no extra $ in the file. One time I fat fingered an extra $ to the html page but couldn't find anything wrong this time.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds you used jQuery library in your template, if so, try to include it in your display template as [the demo](https://devspoint.wordpress.com/2013/08/20/using-jquery-datatables-with-search-display-templates/)

```
<body>
    <script>
        $includeScript(this.url,"~sitecollection/style library/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js");        
    </script>
```